# How to scope an event handler's formal parameter for use in a Fragment.load promise resolution?

Tags: promise, scope, sapui5

How to scope an event handler's formal parameter for use in a Fragment.load promise resolution?

I have built an XML Fragment that contains a sap.m.MessagePopover.  I require the MessagePopover to be able to be opened by any button or control that fires an event.  I have created the event handler in the base controller.  Following best practices, the event handler uses sap.ui.require to load the component and the fragment definition only when the event happens.  The Fragment.load promise resolution then opens the MessagePopover by the control that fired the event.  My issue is that I must create a reference to the event source within the controller's global variables for it to be used within the sap.ui.require/Fragment.load scope.

My question being is it possible to use some promise/callback magic to have oEvent visible within the Fragment.load promise resolution, so I don't have to create the global reference within the controller?

P.S. Please ignore the fact that the fragment should be stored in a controller variable for use on subsequent calls.

This is the fragment file

```
<core:FragmentDefinition
    xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
    <MessagePopover 
        items="{messages&gt;/}">
        <MessageItem
            activeTitle="{/useActiveTitle}"
            description="{i18n&gt;DESCRIPTION}"
            subtitle="{i18n&gt;SUBTITLE}"
            title="{messages&gt;message}" 
            type="{messages&gt;type}" />
    </MessagePopover>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

Within my test view, I have the following button.

```
<Button
    id="btnViewMessages"
    icon="sap-icon://message-popup"
    press=".onMessageButtonPress"
    text="{= ${messages>/}.length }"
    tooltip="{i18n&gt;VIEW_MESSAGES}"
    type="Emphasized"
    visible="{= ${messages>/}.length > 0}" />
```

The following is the event handler that will display the fragment.  This is where I would like to have oEvent available within `.then()`

```
/**
 * Handle a control event to display a MessagePopover next to the control.
 * @function
 * @public
 * @param {sap.ui.base.Event} [oEvent]
 */
 onMessageButtonPress: function (oEvent) {
    // This is where I must to create a reference to the source for later use
    this._oSource = oEvent.getSource();

    sap.ui.require([
        "sap/ui/core/Fragment"
    ], function(Fragment) {
        Fragment.load({
            name: "testControls.view.fragments.MessagePopover"
        })
        .then(function (oFragment) {
            this.getView().addDependent(oFragment);
            // Here I would like to somehow scope oEvent to be able to use it here 
            // instead of having to use the controller's global variable _oSource.
            oFragment.openBy(this._oSource);
        }.bind(this));
    }.bind(this));
 }
```

For testing, you can use the following onInit in the controller to have messages available for the MessagePopover.

```
onInit: function () {
    // Set the model for the view
    var oViewModel = new JSONModel();
    oViewModel.setData({
        "useActiveTitle": true
    });
    this.getView().setModel(oViewModel);

    // Setup the MessageManager along with view's message model.
    this._MessageManager = sap.ui.getCore().getMessageManager();
    this.getView().setModel(this._MessageManager.getMessageModel(), "messages");
    this._MessageManager.registerObject(this.getView(), true);
    this._MessageManager.addMessages(
        new Message({
            message: "Enter a valid number for seconds to display busy UI",
            type: library.MessageType.Error,
            target: "/Dummy",
            processor: this.getView().getModel()
    }));
    this._MessageManager.addMessages(
        new Message({
            message: "Fix all errors to coninue",
            type: library.MessageType.Info,
            target: "/Dummy",
            processor: this.getView().getModel()
        }));
}
```

To reiterate my expectation, I would like to use `oFragment.openBy(oEvent.getSource())` instead of the controller's global variable _oSource.

Comment: why not do a `var oFragment = sap.ui.xmlfragment(fragmentId, context)`? it does all the heavy lifting...

Comment: Because sap.ui.xmlfragment is marked as deprecated

Comment: oEvent should be available in your promise, since it's the same scope. Simply use oEvent directly?!

Comment: oEvent is undefined in the then() scope.  Also, matbtt's comment is correct.  This is why sap.ui.xmlfragment is not used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately Event instance is reset after all handlers have taken a chance to process it. So by the time your Fragment promise is resolved the event instance is reset by SAPUI5 ObjectPool module: you can see it in [Event.js implementation](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/base/Event.js) (lines 74-78).

Instead of making a property to **this** object you can use just a local variable for event source, it will be available in promise resolution as part of closure:

```
onMessageButtonPress: function (oEvent) {
    // This is where I must to create a reference to the source for later use
    var oSource = oEvent.getSource();

    sap.ui.require([
        "sap/ui/core/Fragment"
    ], function(Fragment) {
        Fragment.load({
            name: "testControls.view.fragments.MessagePopover"
        })
        .then(function (oFragment) {
            this.getView().addDependent(oFragment);
            // Here I would like to somehow scope oEvent to be able to use it here 
            // instead of having to use the controller's global variable _oSource.
            oFragment.openBy(oSource);
        }.bind(this));
    }.bind(this));
 }
```

Comment: So reset() is being called on the Event.  This explains the behavior I am seeing with the formal parameter.  Thanks slkorolev!